# Appium timeout too long when using MobileElement

Tags: java, appium

I'm writing Appium tests that runs against both Android and ioS. When I try to find a MobileElement that's not visable, the timeout takes more than the specified time. If I use a By.id, the timeout is correct.

Timeouts after 45 s

```
@AndroidFindBy(id = "ok_button")
private MobileElement okButton;

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(okButton));
```

Timeouts after 5 s

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("ok_button")));
```

Comment: `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));`, shouldn't it be 'okButton' instead of 'element' ?

Comment: You're right, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your page object constructor:

```
PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS), this);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my view, checking for element availability and unavailability is the best way instead of mentioning the TIMEOUT seconds for a wait.(because there might be a possible internet speed issues!!)

```
public boolean isElementPresent(WebElement elementName, int timeout){
        try{
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(AppiumController.instance.driver, timeout);
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(elementName));
                return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
}
```